# bash outputting log lines or parts of lines in color

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, syntax-highlighting

I am using Mac terminal, ssh to a bash account on Linux

I already have the following applying color to my command line prompt:

```
#bash_profile
parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
export PS1="\[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

So the `[\033..` part does that.

However, I'd like to also do this to console logs on php scripts I'm running, specifically to color the date and trace id lighter so they don't focus on as much:

```
Aug 12 16:08:04.5072 [d05lo653148oocks0ook4oc04] [warning] Hash value: 39d26fdee9eb472ab72dafbaf88801b5
Aug 12 16:08:04.5146 [d05lo653148oocks0ook4oc04] [ORM] [debug] Kernel_Core_Orm::commit
```

And perhaps to color `[warning]` for example a different color.

How would I do this?

Comment: Are you looking to generate the logs with the color tags in them, or do you want to add the color tags after the fact (eg, via `sed` or `awk`)? I just ran a google search on `colorize php logs` and received quite a few hits ... have you already run a similar search and ruled out those ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check it:

```sh
$ php -r 'echo "\033[38;5;1mgood \033[38;3;2mluck \033[0mdude\n";'
```

\033[  -> escape char
38     -> foreground, use 48 for background.
5      -> don't know, you tell me ;-)
1      -> red, range is from 0 to 255.
m      -> close escape

The last part, `\033[0m`, resets to the default terminal colour.

In your case, use something like the following.

```php
<?php
echo "\033[38;5;6mAug 12 16:08:04.5072\033[0m [d05lo653148oocks0ook4oc04] \033[38;5;11m[warning]\033[0m Hash value: 39d26fdee9eb472ab72dafbaf88801b5";
```

I've written a article about it once, [check](http://nerveware.org/terminal-markup/1.html) it out.